# How do I keep my system up to date with Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, apt, update

Occasionally, my Raspbmc upgrades itself, downloading and installing new kernels and xbmc. How would I keep the other packages up-to-date?

I'm not sure if it's recommended, but I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It seems like some packages are put on hold, although surprisingly, others were still uninstalled. Should I not have run these commands?

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnss-winbind libpam-winbind samba
The following packages have been kept back:
  libwbclient0 samba-common smbclient winbind xbmc
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 21.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 33369 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libnss-winbind:armhf ...
Removing libpam-winbind:armhf ...
Removing samba ...
[ ok ] Stopping Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.
```

Subsequent attempts at `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` resulted in no packages being upgraded or installed.

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
initscripts                 hold
insserv                     hold
libavahi-client3:armhf      hold
lsb-base                    hold
lsb-release                 hold
manpages                    hold
network-manager             hold
rsyslog                     hold
udev                        hold
upstart                     hold
winbind                     hold
xinetd                      hold
```

Answer (score 2):

`upgrade` will never alter which packages are installed, it will only update those that are installed to the latest version it can. It **will not upgrade a package if that would require installing new dependencies**, and it will not remove unnecessary packages.

`dist-upgrade` ***will* (un)install dependencies as needed**. As far as I know, it’s equivalent to `install [list of all explicitly installed pkgs]` (but there may be differences). This is *good*, dependencies are bound to change, and you want your system to reflect that, obviously.

> Aside: Some people say `dist-upgrade` is dangerous (e.g., if you have stuff that depends on certain packages, but does not declare this [which is bad form, I’d say]). If you’re in a 
>   production environment and want your system to be as stable as possible, then this *might* be a concern. For the record: If you *are* worried, use `install [package you care about]` to selectively "`dist-upgrade`" only some packages, rather than all.

Assuming you don’t use your Pi for mission-critical stuff, **`dist-upgrade` does exactly what you want**, so you’re good. There’s no need to run both, by the way, because `d-u` will do what `u` does and more.

As for packages being held back: This probably due to (at the moment) unresolvable dependencies, but should go away once those deps are available.

Comment: A few things: this question is (partially) specific to Raspbmc. In the past, `apt-get upgrade` was not recommended, and could kill the system. Also, what do you mean by "should go away once those deps are available"? AFAIK they are available; as per my last command, they are manually held back.

Comment: If Raspbmc put a hold on those pkgs, they apparently don't want you to update them. I didn't know that Raspbmc handles things differently, sorry. (My opinion is that if `dist-upgrade` let alone a simple `upgrade` can break the system, then there's something wrong with that design.)

Comment: IIRC I think there was some discussion about why previous iterations of Raspbmc didn't disable apt-get upgrade totally, although I guess this would prevent upgrade of manually-install packages. But yes, I agree that if it can still break the system, it's a suboptimal setup.